# Why is it possible to neglect higher order terms in the variation of the action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

In order to get the Euler-Lagrange equations, we should find the variation of the action $\delta S$ and to neglect higher-order terms:

$$\delta S=\int L(q+\delta q,\,q'+\delta q',\,t)dt-\int L(q ,\,q',\,t)dt+O[(\delta q)^2]$$

I have two questions:

1. Why is it legal to neglect the higher-order terms?
2. If we get the Euler-Lagrange equations from a first-order approximation, doesn't it means that the equations themselves are only an approximation?

Comment: It is no approximation. This is calculus of variations. Similarly, if you want to find a stationary point of a (real) function $f$, what do you do/which equation do you have to solve?

Comment: You're not "neglecting" higher order terms.  Like the extremum of a function is fully determined by the first derivative, so the extremum of the integral is fully determined by the first variation.

Comment: The stationary action principle can be stated in terms of the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_derivative) viz. $\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}=0$ or in terms of the [functional differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Functional_differential) viz. $\delta S=0$; but as the above links show, $\delta S$ is defined as a definite integral whose integrand is proportional to $\frac{\delta S}{\delta q}$, which is not quite what you've done.

Comment: Just to rephrase what others have said in a slightly different way: knowing the first order variation *for an arbitrary starting path $q$* is *much more information* than knowing the first order variation *for one specific path $q$*. The former is like knowing the entire first derivative of a function, the latter is only knowing the first derivative at a single point. Knowing the first derivative at all points is enough information to find stationary points.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero. Interesting. You may want to make a formal answer using your idea. It would be nice to show why variational calculus is only interested in the first order term.

Comment: @Sedumjoy as requested: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is *not mathematical rigorous*, but a *sketch* of the central ideas.

To start, let us consider the case of a (differentiable) real scalar function $f:   \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$. We say that $x$ is a stationary point if and only if $f^\prime(x)=0$. The Taylor expansion of $f$ around a point $x$ is given by:

$$f(x+h) = f(x) + f^\prime(x)  \, h + \mathcal O(h^2) \quad. \tag{1} $$

Now if $x$ is a stationary point, we have $f^\prime(x) =0$, which regarding equation $(1)$ yields

$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = \mathcal O(h^2)\tag{2} \quad . $$

What this means is that small changes of $x$ induce only changes to second (and higher) order in $f$ if $x$ is a stationary point.
Conversely, if equation $(2)$ holds, then $x$ is a stationary point, which can be seen by dividing $(2)$ with $h$ and taking the limit $h \to 0$, yielding $f^\prime(x)=0$.

This also means that you can find the stationary points of $f$ by (Taylor) expanding it in terms of $h$ and set the terms proportional to $h$ to zero. But we don't neglect any terms or approximate anything.

---

The very same line of thought applies to functionals: Indeed, consider a functional $S:F\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, with a suitable chosen space of functions $F$.
We define the $n$-th functional derivative as
$$ \delta^{n} S[f][\eta]:=\frac{\mathrm d^n S[f+\epsilon \, \eta]}{\mathrm d \epsilon^n} \big\vert_{\epsilon=0}\tag{3} \quad ,$$
where $\epsilon \in  \mathbb R$ and $\eta$ denotes a suitable function. We can further define a Taylor series as follows:

$$ S[f+h\eta] = S[f] + \sum\limits_{n=1} \frac{h^n}{n!}\, \delta^{n} S[f][\eta] \tag{4}$$

We say that $S$ is stationary at $f$ if the first functional derivative vanishes for all $\eta$, or, equivalently, $S$ does not change to first order for a small change of $f$, i.e. for all $\eta$ we have
$$ S[f+h \eta] - S[f] = \mathcal O(h^2)\tag{5} \quad .$$

Again, note that $(5)$ is equivalent to say that the functional derivative of $S$ at $f$ vanishes.

Comment: Is (5) equivalent to saying that the functional derivative of $S$ at $f$ vanishes because when you take the limit $h\rightarrow 0$, the RHS of (5) will vanish?

Comment: @physics_fan_123 Well, if you divide by $h$ and take the limit $h\to 0$, then the LHS is simply the functional derivative, cf. equation $(3)$ for $n=1$. On the RHS there are only terms at least proportional to $h$, so they'll vanish in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

We want to fund the function $y(x)$ that  will minimize
$$
I=\int_{a}^{b}dx\,F(x,y(x),y^{\prime }(x))\, , \tag{1}
$$
where the integrand
depends $x$, $y(x)$ and also on the derivative $y^{\prime }(x)$.
Obviously, more general integrands, which could depend on higher
derivatives of $y$ are possible but they are not needed for our
immediate purpose, so we'll stick to the next simplest case, at
least as far as derivatives are concerned.

We introduce $Y(x,\varepsilon)=y(x)+\varepsilon\gamma(x)$,
with $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)=0$, so that the integral now becomes a
parametrized integral
$$
I(\varepsilon)=\int_{a}^{b}dx\,F(x,Y(x,\varepsilon),Y^{\prime}(x,\varepsilon)).
$$
Moreover, the function $y(x)$ is assumed to be *the* function that minimizes (1).  As the function $\gamma(x)$ is basically arbitrary, the function $Y(y,x,\epsilon)$ is basically also arbitrary.  Moreover, it is clear that $Y(x,0)=y(x)$.

Since the integral is now a function of the parameter $\epsilon$, we can just take $dI(\epsilon)/d\epsilon$ and find where this derivative is $0$.  Moreover, if we set $\epsilon=0$ at that point, we know that $Y$ will collapse to $y$, which is the function we're searching for.

Using the chain rule for partial derivatives, we have
$$
\frac{dI(\varepsilon)}{d\varepsilon}=\int_{a}^{b}dx\left(
\frac{\partial
F(x,Y(x,\varepsilon),Y^{\prime}(x,\varepsilon))}{\partial
Y}\frac{\partial
Y(x,\varepsilon)}{\partial\varepsilon}+\frac{\partial
F(x,Y(x,\varepsilon ),Y^{\prime}(x,\varepsilon))}{\partial
Y^{\prime}}\frac{\partial Y^{\prime
}(x,\varepsilon)}{\partial\varepsilon}\right) ,
$$
and
$$
\left( \frac{dI(\varepsilon)}{d\varepsilon}\right)
_{\varepsilon=0}=\int _{a}^{b}dx\left( \frac{\partial
F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial y}
\gamma(x)+\frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial y^{\prime}}\frac{%
d\gamma(x)}{dx}\right) ,   \tag{2}
$$
where we use the fact that $Y(x,0)=y(x)$ at $\epsilon=0$.

When $y^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is continuous, we can integrate the
second term
by part and obtain, using $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)=0,$%
$$
\int_{a}^{b}dx \frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial
y^{\prime}}
\frac{d\gamma(x)}{dx}=\left(\frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))} {\partial y^{\prime}}\gamma(x)\right)\Bigl\vert_{a}^{b}   \\
 -\int_{a}^{b}dx\left(\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{%
\partial y^{\prime}}\right)\gamma(x) \, .
$$

The first part on the right of the equality disappears by virtue of
the boundary conditions, and the second part can be combined with
the first term in Eqn. (2) to obtain
$$
\left( \frac{dI(\varepsilon)}{d\varepsilon}\right)
_{\varepsilon=0}=\int
_{a}^{b}dx\left( \frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial y}-\frac {d}{dx}\frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial
y^{\prime}}\right) \gamma(x).
$$
Again, since $\gamma(x)$ is arbitrary, we have
$$
\left( \frac{dI(\varepsilon)}{d\varepsilon}\right) _{\varepsilon
=0}=0\Longrightarrow\frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial y}-%
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F(x,y(x),y^{\prime}(x))}{\partial
y^{\prime}}=0\, .
$$
The symbol
$$
\left( \frac{dI(\varepsilon)}{d\varepsilon}\right) _{\varepsilon
=0}\equiv \delta I
$$
So really one never needs to expand anything to "beyond first order" since the problem is really one of considering the *first* derivative of a parametrized integral since we're only interested in the extrema of the integral.

Comment: Thank you for following up on my suggestion. This is a really nice job of it.

Comment: @Sedumjoy no worries.  The English could be improved but I don't think there's any significant error in the math.